# In which part of the calculation have I gone wrong? (Change of Basis)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Given a $\mathbb{C}$-vectorspace $V=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{bmatrix}$ for $a,b∈ \mathbb{C}$ and a basis of $V$ by $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, set $T : V → V$ to be the linear transformation such that $$_C[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}1+i&i\\2+i&1+i\end{bmatrix}.$$

From this, we deduce that $$T\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}=(1+i)\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}+(2+i)\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1+i\\-1-i&1\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$T\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}=(i)\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}+(1+i)\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}1&i\\-i&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

From the second part, we get that $A$, which is a matrix corresponding to $T$ is $\begin{bmatrix}i&-1\\1&i\end{bmatrix}$.

However, if I substitute this into the first part, it won't work:

$$\begin{bmatrix}i&-1\\1&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}≠\begin{bmatrix}1&1+i\\-1-i&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: in the notation $_C[T]_B$ it is not clear if $B$ is the basis of the domain or the codomain of $T$

Comment: @Masacroso I don't think that is going to be a problem - for all the other questions it worked well

Comment: I cannot say where you are wrong if I dont understand your notation, so yes, it is a problem

Comment: @Masacroso I am really sorry, can't understand your point. (Probably because I just woke up and my brains not functioning properly) Could you just clarify what you are saying

Comment: What do you mean by $_C[T]_B$?

Comment: I think the notation $_C[T]_B$ means, matrix representation of the linear transformation with basis $C$ fixed on domain and basis $B$ fixed on range... Recall that, to represent a linear transformation$T:V\rightarrow W$ as a matrix, we need to fix a basis for $V$ and a basis for $W$..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Based on the calculations in the question, I think you’ve gotten it backwards. One of them should be the basis of the _codomain_ instead of the _range_, at any rate: the range might not be all of $V$.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The title suggests that this is a change-of-basis exercise, but you’ve only given the original bases for the matrix of $T$. What is it that you’re meant to compute?

Comment: Also, the “first part” and “second part” of what? Seems like there’s quite a bit of context missing from your question.

Answer (score 1):

It’s unclear from your question what exactly it is that you’re meant to do in this exercise. However, when checking your work at the end it appears that you’ve made the error of confusing elements of $V$ with their coordinates relative to some basis. The former are $2\times2$ matrices with complex entries, but the latter are elements of $\mathbb C^2$, i.e., two-dimensional complex vectors. To put it another way, denoting the standard basis by $E$, you’ve computed $_E[T]_E v$ instead of $_E[T]_E[v]_E$. If $V$ had been defined as, say, the set of complex matrices of the form $\small{\begin{bmatrix}a&b&b\\-b&a&b\\-b&-b&a\end{bmatrix}}$ instead, there would’ve been no possibility of making this mistake. This space is also two-dimensional, so the matrix of any $T:V\to V$ is $2\times2$, hence the product $_E[T]_E v$ is undefined.